# Redirect calls not from my contacts to another phone number?

Tags: contacts, calls

Is there any way to redirect/forward calls that are not from my contacts to another number?

(No, I'm not looking to block them or redirect them to voicemail.)

Comment: Related https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/123942/forwarding-calls-from-certain-callers?rq=1

Comment: @Reddy: Is the first sentence in the answer a typo? It says "I doubt that this will not be possible for an app to do".

Comment: I wrote "Related". Whether things have changed since that answer is something else.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio: Yeah I imagine they haven't changed much, but that's not what I meant -- I meant the answer says "I *doubt* that this will *not* be possible" (i.e. it is probably possible) but then proceeds to argue why "I *doubt* that this *will* be possible" (i.e. it is probably impossible).

Comment: @Mehrdad thanks for spotting the typo in my answer. Fixed it. I believe your current question is a dupe of that and am voting to close on this account. You can always edit your question to say why it is not. Thanks