# Forwarding incoming calls to landline when connected to specific wifi-network

Tags: wi-fi, calls

I have the following problem: In my house, it is practically impossible to take a call on the mobile phone due to very bad mobile network connection. As soon as I am more than 2-3 meters away from any window both me and the person who called me cannot hear each other anymore. Probably the walls are made of a lot of reinforced concrete which creates interference. I wonder if there's any possibility to forward incoming calls to my landline phone whenever I am connected to the wifi in my house?

I read [this article](https://www.techjunkie.com/best-call-forwarding-apps-android/) and came upon the app [Call Divert](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.blueskyapps.calldivert&hl=en_US&gl=US) but it seems that this app is full of ads. Is there any open source solution that does the same thing?

Comment: My first thought for such things usually is [tag:tasker] (not open source, but no ads etc. either). There might be other [tag:automation] tools capable of that. They can act on events and states (in your case, "WiFi connected, SID xxx") and perform tasks. Not sure if any 3rd party app is allowed to do call divert in recent Android versions, with Google always taking away such things in the name of security (and yes, Call Divert is [full of ads & trackers](https://reports.exodus-privacy.eu.org/en/reports/157055/)).

Comment: Hmm, I installed Tasker but it seems not to be straightforward to divert **incoming** calls with this app (diverting outgoing calls is fairly easy). I found these two pages that lead might lead to a possible solution but I don't know how to implement these suggestions into a working task ([tasker-homepage](https://tasker.joaoapps.com/userguide/en/faqs/faq-how.html#n), [google-groups-page](https://groups.google.com/g/tasker/c/pTDOb_YrGio?pli=1))

Comment: Also, found out that my question is a [duplicate](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/123942/forwarding-calls-from-certain-callers/123946#123946)

Comment: Yeah, Tasker has quite a steep learning curve. Took me several months for the basics (and now I always have to research again – as once set up I never felt the need to touch it again :D) // Shall I close this question as duplicate then? I'd say yours is a little more specific (certain number PLUS certain WiFi).

Comment: "Shall I leave this question as duplicate then?" I guess based on your reasoning you could leave this open, as my question is basically building up on this question

Comment: there is a straight forward app that automatically redirects your cellphone to landline based on WiFi connection  [Forward My Calls](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stt.forwardmycall)

Comment: Yet, It seems to be very old and unsupported, so tell us how you found it

Comment: Rather strange that there are no similar apps as far as I searched
Location based automatic calls forwarding